# How can I randomize a background video on refresh on a one page website?

Tags: javascript, html, bulma

I'm currently working on a one page website project using the Bulma framework, and my site currently has one background video that plays as the user scrolls through the site. However, I'd like to possibly add some more videos and have a different one play randomly on refresh. I have found JS code that works, but it pulls videos from the internet, whereas mine are saved in a folder; when I put the filenames in, it doesn't work.

Here's the JS code that worked for me at first

```
var videoStorage = [ 
'//media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer',
'//techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small',
'//fat.gfycat.com/DazzlingCompleteAnkole',
'//zippy.gfycat.com/HeavyPlumpIvorybilledwoodpecker'
],
    video = document.querySelector('video'),
    // choose one random url from our storage as the active video
    activeVideoUrl = videoStorage[Math.round(Math.random() * (videoStorage.length - 1))];        

// check which file extension your browser can play and set the video source accordingly
if(video.canPlayType('video/webm')) {
    video.setAttribute('src', activeVideoUrl + '.webm');
} else if(video.canPlayType('video/mp4')) {
    video.setAttribute('src', activeVideoUrl + '.mp4');
}
```

Here's the HTML I have for the one video so far

```
<section id="home" class="hero is-fullheight-with-navbar video">
    <div class="hero-video">
        <video id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="images/i_know_what_i_like.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
```

Since that JS code did do its job, is there a way to make it work using the files I have saved in a folder?

Comment: folder? how is it any different than the urls you have now? Instead of a url to another site it is a url to the file on your site.

Comment: @epascarello The videos in that JS code aren't mine, they're from the code I found online. I did try changing the URLs in JS but that didn't do it for me. So var videoStorage = [ "images/i_know_what_i_like.mp4", etc" didn't work out

Comment: How did you change the urls?

Comment: @epascarello var videoStorage = [ "images/i_know_what_i_like.mp4", etc. ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the notes. I expect your url was not loading because you were providing the extension. E.g: `images/i_know_what_i_like.mp4` would become `images/i_know_what_i_like.mp4.mp4` or `images/i_know_what_i_like.mp4.webp`, which probably aren't existing url's.

One solution would be to not add the extension with JS.

```
// NOTE: make sure these are valid working urls.
var videoStorage = [ 
'images/i_know_what_i_like.mp4'
];
let video = document.querySelector('video');
// choose one random url from our storage as the active video
// NOTE: you don't want to use Math.round() here, use Math.floor() instead
let activeVideoUrl = videoStorage[Math.floor(Math.random() * videoStorage.length];        

// NOTE: you are providing the extension so no need to add it in JS
video.setAttribute('src', activeVideoUrl);
```

Comment: Something I did forget to mention is that I'm randomizing an image on refresh as well, so when I tried implementing the code in JS, the images went away. I now have images and videos in separate folders, so the main thing to deal with now is the conflict between the random images and videos. However, the videos didn't randomize on refresh quite yet.

Comment: You could use a regExp to detect an extension and create an image or video element when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use full path:

```
    var videoStorage = [ 
     'https://example.com/videso/test1.mp4',
     'https://example.com/videso/test2.mp4',
     'https://example.com/videso/test3.mp4',
     'https://example.com/videso/test4.mp4',
     'https://example.com/videso/test5.mp4'
    ],
        video = document.querySelector('video'),
        // choose one random url from our storage as the active video
        activeVideoUrl = videoStorage[Math.round(Math.random() * (videoStorage.length - 1))];        

  video.setAttribute('src', activeVideoUrl)
```